# text-overflow:ellipsis doesn't work limited lines of display

Tags: css

jsfiddle code :
https://jsfiddle.net/JaneChen/gu7tf864/1/

```
<span class="fileName" >long name file to display long name file to displayddddddssdd moreggggg lines more lines more more more lines</span>
```

.scss:

```
.fileName {
   @font-size: 17px;
   @line-height: 1.3;
   @lines-to-show: 3;

  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    display: inline-block;


  overflow:hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;


  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 175px;


  font-size: 17px;
  line-height:  1.4;
  max-height: 71.4px;
}
```

The text block shows as 3 lines, but The ellipsis doesn't show when the text is truncated.  Why is that ? Is there a way to fix? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot

```
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot about

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

check the result in
https://jsfiddle.net/gu7tf864/3/

Comment: Then the text block is showed only in one line . Limited lines of text is kind of an essential condition in this problem.  Thanks though.